# iFrame border render error on resize

Tags: iframe

The following Electron-based application is divided into five elements by vertical iFrames. On resize, the then blue borders sometimes render an additional white-colored line of one pixel width.

[image]

I can reproduce this error in latest versions of Edge, Chrome and FireFox.

Before the discussion comes up: No, I'm sorry, removing the iframes is not an option (for reasons unrelated to this question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While typing this question I came up with an idea: What's actually visible when these white lines appear?

It's the background of the surrounding index.html file, which by default is white. While the lines are still there, changing the background color to match the respective iframe background color does effectively hide them from sight.